The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted chunks and assets must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths
what i am using: vue3, pnpm, vite
PROBLEM: i have a pnpm workspace and there is two folder for workspaces, packages which contain a project called "shared" for common stuff, and a folder called "apps" that contains 4 projects. one of these four projects is named "root" and it is there to unify the other three (for now of course) and use the advantage of SPA routing (it is a simple projects that just has a vue-router instance and imports other projects App.vue files and use them on a child-route e.g. /panel or /scada). i can build all the app/* projects successfully except for root project, it throws the error bellow:

vite v5.3.1 building for production...
│
│ (!) outDir C:\Projects\Frontend-Test2\Frontend\dist\root is not inside project root and will not be emptied.
│ Use --emptyOutDir to override.
│
│ transforming...
│ ✓ 75 modules transformed.
│ rendering chunks...
│ x Build failed in 11.01s
│ error during build:
│ [vite:build-html] The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted chunks and assets must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths, received "../service-panel/index.html".
│     at getRollupError (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:396:41)
│     at error (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:392:42)
│     at FileEmitter.emitFile (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19278:24)
│     at Object.generateBundle (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1_@types+node@20.14.5_less@4.2.0_terser@5.31.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:35257:14)
│     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
│     at async Bundle.generate (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18153:9)
│     at async file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20692:27
│     at async catchUnfinishedHookActions (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.18.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:20119:16)
│     at async build (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1_@types+node@20.14.5_less@4.2.0_terser@5.31.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BcXSligG.js:65670:16)
│     at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Projects/Frontend-Test2/Frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.3.1_@types+node@20.14.5_less@4.2.0_terser@5.31.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:828:5)
└─ Failed in 20.1s at C:\Projects\Frontend-Test2\Frontend\apps\root


build error for root projects
WHAT I NEED: i need the root project successfully build and run with vite preview and have a functional SPA routing. in the mean while i need the build folder for each project to be different in the dist folder (i currently have 4 folder in my dist folder located in the root of the pnpm, service-panel, scada, ticketing, root - the root folder on /dist/root should have 3 folder in it named after each project and one index.html from root project and build them in there when i run vite build in the root project i have done this before but i could failed to recreate it again) and i need the tailwind styles to get fixed (some styles like flex and flex-row will be compiled but other styles don't - like bg-green-200 or w-10)
Thank you all...
project folder structure
+---apps
¦   +---root
¦   ¦   +---cypress
¦   ¦   ¦   +---e2e
¦   ¦   ¦   +---fixtures
¦   ¦   ¦   +---support
¦   ¦   +---public
¦   ¦   +---src
¦   ¦   ¦   +---assets
¦   ¦   ¦   +---components
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---__tests__
¦   ¦   ¦   +---router
¦   ¦   ¦   +---stores
¦   ¦   ¦   +---views
¦   +---scada
¦   ¦   +---cypress
¦   ¦   ¦   +---e2e
¦   ¦   ¦   +---fixtures
¦   ¦   ¦   +---support
¦   ¦   +---public
¦   ¦   +---src
¦   ¦   ¦   +---assets
¦   ¦   ¦   +---components
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---icons
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---__tests__
¦   ¦   ¦   +---router
¦   ¦   ¦   +---stores
¦   ¦   ¦   +---views
¦   +---service-panel
¦   ¦   +---cypress
¦   ¦   ¦   +---e2e
¦   ¦   ¦   +---fixtures
¦   ¦   ¦   +---support
¦   ¦   +---public
¦   ¦   +---src
¦   ¦   ¦   +---assets
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---fonts
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---iran_sans
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---iran_yekan
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---images
¦   ¦   ¦   +---components
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   +---Layout
¦   ¦   ¦   +---router
¦   ¦   ¦   +---stores
¦   ¦   ¦   +---views
¦   ¦   ¦       +---Auth
¦   ¦   ¦       ¦   +---Login
¦   ¦   ¦       +---Dashboard
¦   +---ticketing
¦       +---cypress
¦       ¦   +---e2e
¦       ¦   +---fixtures
¦       ¦   +---support
¦       +---public
¦       +---src
¦       ¦   +---assets
¦       ¦   ¦   +---css
¦       ¦   ¦   +---fonts
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   +---iran_sans
¦       ¦   ¦   ¦   +---iran_yekan
¦       ¦   ¦   +---images
¦       ¦   +---components
¦       ¦   ¦   +---icons
¦       ¦   ¦   +---__tests__
¦       ¦   +---router
¦       ¦   +---stores
¦       ¦   +---views
+---packages
    +---shared
        +---cypress
        ¦   +---e2e
        ¦   +---fixtures
        ¦   +---support
        +---public
        +---src
            +---assets
            ¦   +---css
            ¦   +---fonts
            ¦   ¦   +---iran_sans
            ¦   ¦   +---iran_yekan
            ¦   +---images
            +---components
            ¦   +---ActionSheets
            ¦   +---Carts
            ¦   +---Charts
            ¦   +---icons
            ¦   +---Layout
            ¦   +---Map
            ¦   +---Support
            +---layouts
            ¦   +---auth
            ¦   +---main
            ¦       +---Asides
            ¦       +---SubComponents
            ¦           +---Aside1
            ¦           +---Aside2
            ¦               +---Level2
            ¦               +---Level3
            +---router
            +---stores
            +---views
                +---Errors
                +---PublicPages


bellow i will share necessary files to check (comment if any other files would be needed):
root directory of pnpm workspace files:
package.json:

{
  "name": "flowmeter-pnpm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "build:all": "pnpm recursive run build",
    "test:e2e": "start-server-and-test preview http://localhost:4173 'cypress run --e2e'",
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test 'vite dev --port 4173' http://localhost:4173 'cypress open --e2e'"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress-real-events": "^1.11.0",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.9.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0",
    "vue3-cookies": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.12.23",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "cypress": "^13.7.2",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^2.0.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.8",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "^7.0.25",
    "vitest": "^1.4.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-istanbul": "^1.3.1",
    "@vitest/ui": "^1.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^3.2.2",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}


pnpm-workspaces.yaml file:

packages:
  - 'apps/*'
  - 'packages/*'


project "root":
package.json:

{
  "name": "root",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "test:e2e": "start-server-and-test preview http://localhost:4173 'cypress run --e2e'",
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test 'vite dev --port 4173' http://localhost:4173 'cypress open --e2e'"
  }
}


vite.config.js:

import {fileURLToPath, URL} from 'node:url'

import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'
import {resolve} from 'path'

const __parent = __dirname.split("\\");
__parent.pop();

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({template: {transformAssetUrls: {base: null, includeAbsolute: false}}}),
        VueDevTools(),
    ],
    build: {
        outDir: '../dist/root',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                'service-panel': resolve('../service-panel/index.html'),
            },
            // input: {
            //     'panel': resolve(__parent.join("\\"), 'service-panel\\index.html'),
            //     'scada': resolve(__parent.join("\\"), 'scada\\index.html'),
            //     'support': resolve(__parent.join("\\"), 'ticketing\\index.html')
            // },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: '[name]/assets/[name].js',
                chunkFileNames: '[name]/assets/[name].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name]/assets/[name].[ext]'
            }
        }
    },
    server: {port: 4180},
    preview: {port: 4180},
    esbuild: {target: "esnext"},
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@root': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
            '@pooyac/apps': fileURLToPath(new URL('../../apps', import.meta.url)),
            '@pooyac/shared': fileURLToPath(new URL('../../packages/shared', import.meta.url)),
        }
    }
})


tailwind.config.js:

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


router.js:

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Panel from '@pooyac/apps/service-panel/src/App.vue';
import Scada from '@pooyac/apps/scada/src/App.vue';
import Ticketing from '@pooyac/apps/ticketing/src/App.vue';
import PathNotFound from '@pooyac/shared/src/views/Errors/Error404.vue';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    { path: '/service-panel', component: Panel },
    { path: '/scada', component: Scada },
    { path: '/ticketing', component: Ticketing },
    { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', component: PathNotFound },
  ]
})
export default router;



i used NX but i couldn't get a unified version there too (or maybe i didn't know the flow).
i already used gpt-4, gpt-4o, github copilot, microsoft copilot, stackoverflow and github issues
i think the main problem is the architecture because of the vite limitation to access parent directory using resolve or fileURLToPath


i tried to change __direname value (in another variable called __parent) like bellow and use it in build.rollupOptions.input:


const __parent = __dirname.split("\\");
__parent.pop();


now parent will have the parent directory address and the value was valid, but it does not work duo to vite limitation to access parent directory.

i used these two imports bellow but neither worked:

   
import {fileURLToPath, URL} from 'node:url'
   import {resolve} from 'path'



i tried to make the pnpm workspace root directory (not root project) the root project by transferring all the root projects files to the root folder and it did work (vite limitation was not triggered here because now app directory was a subfolder of the root project) but the output was not as expected (no tailwind style compiled so there was no style and the content was for the older version).


It's better to use code block to show the error log and dir structure than screenshots. Please [edit] the question.

i dropped this approach but i think all the problem is going back to build.rollupOptions.output in vite.config.js, remove it (it is not needed and even better not to transpile all the project in to one js file) and the problem must be gone.
